# nosql separate data by client

Tags: cassandra, couchbase, nosql

I have to develop a project using a NoSql base, either couchbase or cassandra.
I would like to know if it is recommended to partition the data of each customer in a bucket?

In my case, there will never be requests between the different clients.
The data can be completely separated.

For couchbase, I saw that for each bucket a memory capacity, was reserved for him.

Where does the separation have to be done at another place document or super column for cassandra.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Where does the separation have to be done at another place document or super column for cassandra.

Tip #1, when working with Cassandra, **completely erase** the word "super column" from your vocabulary.

> I would like to know if it is recommended to partition the data of each customer in a bucket?

That depends.  It sounds like your queries would be mostly based on a customer id, so it makes sense to have it as a *part* of your partition key.  However, if each customer partition has millions of rows and/or columns underneath it, that's going to get very big.

Tip #2, proper Cassandra modeling is done based on what your required queries look like.  So without actually seeing the kinds of queries you need to serve, it's going to be difficult to be any more specific than that.

If you have customer data relating to accounts and addresses, etc, then building a `customers` table with a PRIMARY KEY of only `customer_id` might make sense.  But if you find that you need to query your customers (for example) by `email_address`, then you'll want to create a `customers_by_email` table, duplicate your data into that, and create a PRIMARY KEY that supports that.

Additionally, if you find yourself storing data on customer activity, you may want to consider a `customer_activity` table with a PRIMARY KEY of `PRIMARY KEY ((customer_id,month),activity_time)`.  That will use both `customer_id` and `month` as a partition key, storing the customer's activity clustered by `activity_time`.  In this case, if we didn't use `month` as an additional partition key, each `customer_id` partition would be continually written to, until it became too ungainly to write to or query (unbound row growth).

**Summary**:

- If anyone tells you to use a super column in Cassandra, **slap them**.
- You need to know your queries *before* you design your tables.
- Yes, `customer_id` would be a good way to keep your data separate and ensure that each query is restricted to a single node.
  -Build your partition keys to account for unbound row growth, to save you from writing too much data into the same partition.

Comment: Great, thank you for your explanation.
The target application comes close to an online accounting application, but almost only in consultation for the client.
The data is added by an automatic process.

I have never used cassandra, just mongoDb in nosql.

(So grouping this done by column families not super column)